# W3C css-validator.jar: Where do I find documentation about local usage (parameters, etc.)?

Tags: java, jar, configuration, w3c-validation

I successfully installed W3C css-validator.jar locally as described here:

[How can I validate CSS on internal web pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137884/is-there-an-open-source-css-validator-that-can-be-run-locally)

Now I'm looking for some documentation about how to use it.

At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
java -jar css-validator.jar --output=soap12 file:source.css > result.xml
```

I'd like to accomplish the following:

- Output in a different format, e.g. XML (I guess that I can simply do `--output xml` for this)
- Input a string directly **without a file**, e.g. `string:"body { color: red; }"`
- Output the result directly **without a file** (so **not** like `> result.xml`) so I can do something like `RESULT = java -jar css-validator.jar...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a lot of information about this, but at least here are some configuration parameters:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/manual.html